# Creating Themes using SASS (maps)

Tags: css, sass, themes

I'm new to SASS and I'm trying to give users the ability to pick different themes for a website. I created a map that looks like this:

```
$theme-map: ( 
   main-theme: (
      primary: #007991,
      secondary: #55D3AE,
      tertiary: #D35555,
      gradientFirstColour: #007991,
      gradientSecondColour: #34EBE9
), 
   test-theme: (
      primary: #1abc9c,
      secondary: #e67e22,
      tertiary: #c0392b,
      gradientFirstColour: #2c3e50,
      gradientSecondColour: #f1c40f
   )
)
```

Now I'm not sure how to loop through these and then apply them to specific elements. Example: I want to choose the main theme and then use the primary color for the background of a button, the secondary color for the background of a div, and the same thing when I chose the test theme. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are many ways to implement this, I have experience with doing something similar in the past, so here is my implementation.

**Step 1**

Create multiple CSS output files for the different themes you have, in your case `main.css` and `test.css`. You could prefix the names as well to make them more understandable, `theme-main.css` and `theme-test.css` for example.

I would advice keeping general styles – like reset, margins, typography – in one file, something like `global.css` and add your themes on top of that in separate files. Load these CSS files on top of each other in your HTML.

Main theme:

```
<link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="theme-main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And test theme:

```
<link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="theme-test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In your project's Sass folder, create `theme-main.scss` and `theme-test.scss`, along `global.scss`.

**Step 2**

Move your theme colors into different partial Sass files and make sure the name of the variables is the same. I would personally create folders within the project's Sass folder with names that match my CSS output files and put these files there.

In your case, create a `_theme-main` and `_theme-test` folder within the Sass folder. Create a file in each folder, name them both `_variables.scss` with the following content:

In `_theme-main/_variables.scss`:

```
$colors: (
    primary: #007991,
    secondary: #55D3AE,
    tertiary: #D35555,
    gradientFirstColour: #007991,
    gradientSecondColour: #34EBE9
);
```

And in `_theme-test/_variables.scss`:

```
$colors: (
    primary: #1abc9c,
    secondary: #e67e22,
    tertiary: #c0392b,
    gradientFirstColour: #2c3e50,
    gradientSecondColour: #f1c40f
);
```

**Step 3**

Load the necessary variables in the files where you need them.

In your file `theme-main.scss`, put:

```
@import '_theme-main/variables';
```

And in your file `theme-test.scss`, put:

```
@import '_theme-test/variables';
```

So far, this ensures that the different theme files can work with different values of the same variables. In truth, the variable `$colors` is just called the same in these two theme files, in reality, they are not the same.

**Step 4**

Create a partial Sass file with the styles you want to apply the themes on.

Because we already put the dependencies of `theme-main.scss` in the `_theme-main` folder and the dependencies of `theme-test.scss` in the `_theme-test` folder, I personally would not want to break this pattern, so I would create a `shared` folder or something similar and put partial Sass files that are imported in multiple Sass files there. You could skip this of course, but I believe this helps keep your project more maintainable.

Staying at your example, create a partial Sass file called `_styles.scss` and put it in your `shared` folder. Put the following code in it:

```
button {
    background-color: map-get($colors, primary);
}

div {
    background-color: map-get($colors, secondary);
}
```

And now all you need to do is import this partial file in your theme files.

In your file `theme-main.scss`, put:

```
@import '_theme-main/variables';
@import 'shared/styles';
```

And in your file `theme-test.scss`, put:

```
@import '_theme-test/variables';
@import 'shared/styles';
```

If I did not make any mistakes, your output CSS files should look like this:

`theme-main.css`:

```
button {
    background-color: #007991;
}

div {
    background-color: #55D3AE;
}
```

`theme-test.css`:

```
button {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

div {
    background-color: #e67e22;
}
```

Let me know if you find this useful or if you have any further questions or concerns.

Comment: thank you for such a great and such detailed answer!! I just have one question, (I'm a beginner btw) how would I active each theme using javascript for example?

Comment: There could be plenty of ways to implement a feature like that as well. I put together [a little demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/pentzzsolt/pen/MrmoBO), take a look! The example assumes that there is exactly one theme CSS file loaded at any given time, so at initial load and later on as well. Also, if you would like the site to remember the choice of a user, you will have to use cookies to store that information and retrieve it when they revisit the site or navigate to a different page.